# Apache spark aggregation: aggregate column based on another column value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aggregate

I am not sure if I am asking this correctly and maybe that is the reason why I didn't find the correct answer so far. Anyway, if it will be duplicate I will delete this question.

I have following data:

```
id | last_updated | count
__________________________
1  | 20190101     | 3
1  | 20190201     | 2
1  | 20190301     | 1
```

I want to group by this data by "id" column, get max value from "last_updated" and regarding "count" column I want keep value from row where "last_updated" has max value. So in that case result should be like that:

```
id | last_updated | count
__________________________
1  | 20190301     | 1
```

So I imagine it will look like that:

```
df
  .groupBy("id")
  .agg(max("last_updated"), ... ("count"))
```

Is there any function I can use to get "count" based on "last_updated" column.

I am using spark 2.4.0.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options, the first the better as for my understanding

**OPTION 1**
Perform a window function over the ID, create a column with the max value over that window function. Then select where the desired column equals the max value and finally drop the column and rename the max column as desired

```
val w  = Window.partitionBy("id")

df.withColumn("max", max("last_updated").over(w))
  .where("max = last_updated")
  .drop("last_updated")
  .withColumnRenamed("max", "last_updated")
```

**OPTION 2**

You can perform a join with the original dataframe after grouping

```
df.groupBy("id")
.agg(max("last_updated").as("last_updated"))
.join(df, Seq("id", "last_updated"))
```

**QUICK EXAMPLE**

**INPUT**

```
df.show
+---+------------+-----+
| id|last_updated|count|
+---+------------+-----+
|  1|    20190101|    3|
|  1|    20190201|    2|
|  1|    20190301|    1|
+---+------------+-----+
```

**OUTPUT**
**Option 1**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions

val w  = Window.partitionBy("id") 

df.withColumn("max", max("last_updated").over(w))
  .where("max = last_updated")
  .drop("last_updated")
  .withColumnRenamed("max", "last_updated")


+---+-----+------------+
| id|count|last_updated|
+---+-----+------------+
|  1|    1|    20190301|
+---+-----+------------+
```

**Option 2**

```
  df.groupBy("id")
      .agg(max("last_updated").as("last_updated")
      .join(df, Seq("id", "last_updated")).show


    +---+-----------------+----------+
    | id|     last_updated|    count |
    +---+-----------------+----------+
    |  1|         20190301|         1|
    +---+-----------------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. Perfect. Both solutions work for me, however I am little bit confused with Option 1. I have never used Window before so I will have to look closer to it to understand what is going on behind the scene. 
But anyway thanks, I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: thanks. Option 1 it's basically retrieving the max value for the required column (las_updated) for each value of the specified window (id).

Comment: I think I got it now. Thnaks